# Media urls not working in category descriptions

Tags: image-upload

I'm having issues with the {media url=""} link in the category descriptions.  They seem to working elsewhere on the site (CMS pages etc).

You can see one of the problematic pages [here](http://185.53.173.217/~birdiefo/the-kitchen.html)

The first broken image on that page appears in the category description like this

```
<img alt="" src="{{media url="wysiwyg/20151201-IMG_0547-300x240.jpg"}}" />
```

Answer (score 2):

Go to Admin/Catalog and enable the option for

"Allow Dynamic Media URLs in Products and Categories"

Change from "No" to "Yes" and then clear cache, {{media url=""}} now works ;)

Answer (score 1):

I cant comment.. But the top Answer from @Fran Horan doesnt work, since this option seems not to be available under Catalog for Magento 2.4.2? How can we enable dynamic media now?

Answer (score 0):

Please change double quote in image path to single quotes

```
<img alt="" src="{{media url='wysiwyg/20151201-IMG_0547-300x240.jpg'}}" />
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm afraid that didn't solve the issue.